# Talend Pass Dynamic values into tSOAP Message

Tags: web, talend

I am using BD5.6.1
i am using the tSOAP component and if i use the blow flow it works fine.
tsoap --> LogRow
I can paste the SOAP Request message into SOAP Message section of the tsoap node and it works fine.. 
But now i want to read the excel file and dynamically pass the value to  SOAP Message of tSOAP component how this can be done?

Sample SOAP Message i need to pass.

```
"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xml\" xmlns:urn=\"urn:HPD_Inc_Create_WS\">
<<urn:HelpDesk_Submit_Service>

<urn:First_Name>   </urn:First_Name>
<urn:Impact>  </urn:Impact>

</urn:HelpDesk_Submit_Service>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>"
```

the parameter is
FirstName values are in the file . I need to read these value from excel file and construct the soap message and then send it to tSOAP Component.

I saw on the forum that we can do that

on tSOAP, define the SOAP message to use a dynamic value passed from tFileInputExcel like this:
"...."+(String)globalMap.get("row1.First_Name")+"..."

//First_name is one of the column defined on tFileInputExcel, this column read the FirstName value from excel file.

But is not work for me

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

[image]

Read your excel file, and for each row (`tFlowToIterate`) call `tSOAP` and send it the message you construct:

```
"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xml\" xmlns:urn=\"urn:HPD_Inc_Create_WS\">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <urn:HelpDesk_Submit_Service>
            <urn:First_Name>" + (String)globalMap.get("row10.FirstName") + "</urn:First_Name>
            <urn:Impact>  </urn:Impact>
        </urn:HelpDesk_Submit_Service>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>"
```

the global variable `row10.FirstName` comes from the `tFlowToIterate` which by default creates a global variable called `rowX.Column` for each incoming row's column, which you can rename in the component settings.

You can also use `tESBConsumer` along with a `tXMLMap` to constuct your message.

Comment: Regarding your question after testing with tJava, it should work. Did you make sure to name your column FirstName in tFileInputExcel's schema ? Could you try to print the output of the file : tFileInputExcel --> tLogRow to see what you get ?